# where is the correct place to put the directive dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have an angular app with a pretty standard setup.

An app.js file that uses and configures ngRoute routes. We have a ng-controller tag on our markup:

```
<body ng-controller='mainController'>...</body>
```

And we have several other routes and controllers mapped in app.js. We also have a directives module and use directives throughout our html code.

No JS code depends on any directives being injected, however the directives module does need to be listed somewhere in a dependency list for them to 'exist' in angular.

We are doing our best to use good practice and keep our dependency lists for each module as tightly-scoped as possible (ie: not listing every dependency in app.js). And have put the directives dependency in our mainController.js file. But this seems arbitrary and possibly even wrong (mainController doesn't use this dependency at all).

So the question is, where is the right place to include the directives module as a dependency?

Just put it at the highest-level: app.js??

Thanks.

Comment: If its directives used in your entire application by several other modules, then yes - app.js is the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this question would be easier to answer with some code snippets.

If those directives aren't some fancy coded, widely resusable components but rather do a specific job in one application, i would not create a external module for them and rather push 'em to the top-level application module.

If they are reused, though, i would declare the directive module as a dependency of the top-level module as you suggested.